# Как сохранять огромные объекты в MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql

Я хочу добавить на сайте блог. В своем кастомном редакторе я собираюсь использовать html-тэги. И запишу в блоге, к примеру:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum.

<img src"..." alt="..." styly="...">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum.

<img src"..." alt="..." styly="...">
```

Эти данные идут в ДБ и когда Юзер будет переходить на страницу с постом - я буду брать данные из ДБ и вставлять их в шаблон страницу для постов.

Вопрос:

Могу ли я передать это как один элемент в MySQL-таблицу? И если да - то как?

P.S. Есть еще у меня мысль: вместо передачи данных в таблицу просто генерировать страницу... Но "красиво ли" выглядит это действие?

Comment: В БД делаете поле типа text. А передаете как любое другое значение

Comment: @Mike Какой "предел" по символа у TEXT?

Comment: @Mike и какой способ лучше? БД или создание страницы?

Comment: обычный text 64Кб. longtext 4 Гб. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Страницу генерировать и сохранять для кеширования нужно. Тогда каждый раз её генерировать не нужно будет. Скачайте исходники какой-либо CMS, того-же WordPress, и посмотрите как там реализованы те или другие вещи.